# How do I join across two engines using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy

I have two large tables on two different Oracle databases and want to establish a join between the two.

I am using two engines and a session with multiple binds, which work wonderfully with queries that only involve either one table. But as soon as I try to join the two I get a DatabaseError: (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

I boiled down the problem to this:

```
engine1 = sqlalchemy.create_engine("oracle+cx_oracle://UN:PW@database1")
engine2 = sqlalchemy.create_engine("oracle+cx_oracle://UN:PW@database2")

metadata_data = MetaData(bind = engine1, schema = "schema1")
metadata_classification = MetaData(bind = engine2, schema = "schema2")

Base = declarative_base()

class data(Base):
    __table__ = Table("mydata", metadata_data,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True), 
    autoload_with = engine1)

class classification(Base):
    __table__ = Table("myclassification", metadata_classification,
    Column('class', Integer, primary_key=True), 
    autoload_with = engine2)

Session = sessionmaker(binds = {data: engine1, classification: engine2})
with Session() as session:
    session.query(data).join(classification, data.consumer_id == classification.id).first()
```

Which gives a DatabaseError.

I know I could get each of the databases into pandas and merge that way. In this case, my dataset is very large (billions of rows) and the amount of data can be reduced by a lot if I can aggregate over consumer classes.

So how can I perform a join between two tables bound to two different oracle engines?

Comment: I'm no expert on sqlalchemy, but I doubt it can do this. What you can do is create a database link between the 2 databases, and issue, in the database where you created the link, a sql joining the local table to the remote one.

Comment: Depending on the data manipulation planned, it could be a significant performance benefit to use a link and do the merge & aggregation in SQL or PL/SQL in one DB, and only then fetch the results to Python (if you even need to do that final step).

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?